# What is result of $\frac{d\bf{A}}{d\bf{x}}=?$

Tags: calculus

What is result of this derivative

$$\frac{d\bf{A}}{d\bf{x}}=?$$

where the $\bf{A}$ is vector area (m$^2$) and $\bf{x}$ vector (direction) (m).

Comment: May be Area gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that

$$d\vec{A}=\frac{d\vec{A}}{d\vec{x}}d\vec{x}=\gamma.d\vec{x}$$

then $\gamma$ should be scalar. So $$\gamma=\frac{dA_x}{dx}=\frac{dA_y}{dy}=\frac{dA_z}{dz}$$

Unless there is some constraint of $A$ or other interpretation than $d\vec{A}=\frac{d\vec{A}}{d\vec{x}}d\vec{x}$, I think in general this expression doesn't mean anything.